# CSRF Value is empty on python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello i am trying to scrape an CSRF token from a website

`s = requests.Session()`  
`r = s.get('https://example.com/login')`  
`print(r.text)`

When i am printing this it gives me the csrf <input> tag but with a empty value
If i visit the website the CSRF token is visible

I tried finding finding it by adding proxies and/or a header

Comment: Could you provide the site url and example of expected result of your code? Thx

Comment: https://windscribe.com/login @GreyMurav

Comment: you has to be logged into the site in order to have csrf token. csrf token has linked to the user session so csrf token will be different for each log in

Comment: If i am not logged in, and visit the website manually and inspect the page the csrf token is visible?

Comment: If you are not logged in, the csrf token does not yet exist and is therefore not visible. Your code is just for the case when the user is not logged into the site.